# Moving uv's between 0-1 space

Tags: uv, baking, mirror

I would like to move my uv exacly one uv screen space to right. I need it for clean bake without gradiends. This is common trick used in 3ds max. How to achive it in blender?
I was pressing x and 1 but it looks like it does not work. (one uv is about 277.345 units)

Answer (score 2):

In *UV Editor* open *N-panel* (**N** key) and enable **Normalized**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you enable the normalize option. You can move the islands by adding '1' to the UV vertex coordinate.

For Example, if my UV island is on the X coordinate 0.66 and I want to move it to the right by one UV Space. I change the X coordinate to 1.66.

Another Example, if my UV island is on the Y coordinate 0.33 and I want to move my UV island 2 UV spaces below. I change the Y coordinate to -1.33

Hope This Helps.